# Altium designiing a component with two models but not the same number of pads

Tags: altium, pins

I'm designing a quartz component.
I would like to use it with differents packages like those ones :
[First Type at RS-Online](http://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/quartz/7537186/?searchTerm=753-7186&relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E525353746F636B4E756D6265724D504E266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C26706D3D5E5C647B337D5B5C732D2F255C2E2C5D5C647B332C347D2426706F3D313426736E3D592673743D52535F53544F434B5F4E554D4245522677633D4E4F4E45267573743D3735332D3731383626)
and
[Second Type at Farnell](http://fr.farnell.com/abracon/abs07-32-768khz-t/quartz-32-768khz-12-5pf-cms/dp/2101347RL)

One of them has 2 pads, the other has the same 2 pads and 2 ground pads.
I designed a schematic with 3 pads among them a power pad which is connected
to GND and invisible.

This works pretty well for the 4 pads package but for the 2 pads package,
when I compile, I get an error "Could not find port 'GND' on model 'QUARTZ_32x15' for pin 'GND'".

Obviously, that's right because there's not any ground pin on the 2 pads package.

So, is there a way to acheive this with something like saying that a pin may
be optionnal or something like this? Or should I build one schematic
for each package?

Comment: There are options to avoid it being a "breakable error", but personally I prefer making just two simple schematic components, because else you're opening the door to a lot of confusion and problems in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely build two schematic symbols in this case (just copy and modify one to add the two GND pins- I would definitely make both GND pins visible so you can see where they are connected on the schematic). They really are quite different components from a footprint point of view.